# Как отключить каскадное удаление в EntityFramework при использовании шаблона Table-Per-Type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm

Есть структура БД:

- Таблица **Organization**. Столбцы `OrganizationId, Name`
- Таблица **Provider**. Столбцы `ProviderId, ProviderName`
- Таблица **Bank**. Столбцы `BankId, BankName`

Таблицы `Bank` и `Provider` ссылаются на `OrganizationId` через `BankId` и `ProviderId` соответственно. В приложении сделана такая модель:

```
public class Organization
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}  

[Table("Providers")]
public class Provider : Organization
{
}

[Table("Banks")]
public class Bank: Organization
{
}
```

При сохранении нового объекта `Provider` создаётся запись в двух таблицах `Provider` и `Organization`.

При удалении объекта `Provider` записи удаляются тоже их двух таблиц. Как отключить каскадное удаление из базовой таблицы (`Organization`)? Чтобы удалялась запись только из `Provider`, а в `Organization` оставалась.

Answer (score 1):

Была похожая проблема: [Cascade delete in entity framework ( table per type inheritance )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064273/cascade-delete-in-entity-framework-table-per-type-inheritance)

Думал может использовать для настройки Fluent API **WillCascadeOnDelete(false)**...

Наткнулся на вот эту страницу: [Режим "Таблица для иерархии (Table per hierarchy)](http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/entity-framework-object-hierarchy-mapping) прочел и понял, что нужно пробовать.

В общем нужно попробовать, кстати, вот еще одна статейка: [How to: Set Up Cascade Delete](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/code-only-mapping/mapping-clr-types-properties-and-associations/advanced-mapping/multi-table-entities/fluent-mapping-mapping-clr-advanced-multi-table-entities-cascade-delete)